# Set Layout Edge Round

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make my layout edge round so I am using card view and
also trying to define my own XML with rounded settings and thus link the XML to the background of the `Linear Layout` but that is also not working.

I have also attached the picture What I am getting from there but I want White `rectangular edges` to be gone-

..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TUMX.png)

```
app:cardCornerRadius="9dp"
```

but here I am getting `rectangular background` and I don't understand where that white background come from. So, here's my code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="9dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/fab_background">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/expense"
            android:id="@+id/expense_image"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/expense_image"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="@string/expense"
            android:id="@+id/expense"
            android:inputType="number"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/note"
            android:id="@+id/note_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_image"
            android:layout_below="@id/expense"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/add_note"
            android:id="@+id/add_note"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/putOn"
            android:layout_below="@id/add_note"
            android:text="@string/put_on"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Set cardbackground as transparent . and assign the color to its immediate child.

Comment: Sorry by transparent you mean white ? And i don't get assign what color to its child (Also white) ? And thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `CardView` as a root for for your alert dialog then do as follows . Let me know if it works .

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    // Your layout goes here

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

If still not work then use `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap` attribute in cardview .
Whereas you can use [android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)  for same appearance without any `CardView`.

Comment: Thanks .. But not working .. I think its the background of Alert Dialogue